# Why are my angles off but movement works in my 2D, birds-eye view game?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry, 2d-games

I'm creating a birds-eye view, 2D game in JS using no engine/library (more for the learning challenge). I've got the character movement working with WASD where the character will either go forward (W) or back (S) depending on their current `direction` (A turns left, D turns right), but when I output the angles (`direction`) during play-time I'm getting unexpected results.

For example, when a player is facing "up" and I press "W", the player moves up, and the `direction` that gets output is `90°` - as expected. When facing "down" and I press "S", the player moves down, and the `direction` is `270°` - as expected.

But, when facing left, and I press "W", the character *does* move left **but** the output `direction` is `0°`, and when facing + moving right, it is `180°` - the exact opposite of what I expect.

These are the functions that move my players:

```
// Turning
    _resetAngle(angle) {
        if (angle >= 360) { return 0 }
        if (angle < 0) { return 359 }
        return angle
    }

    updateDirection(player, keyboardInput) {
        let currentDirection = player.direction
        const turnedLeft = keyboardInput['a']
        const turnedRight = keyboardInput['d']

        if (turnedLeft) { currentDirection -= this.turnAngle }
        if (turnedRight) { currentDirection += this.turnAngle }

        player.setDirection(this._resetAngle(currentDirection))
    }

//Moving
    _calculateNewCoords(movingForward, entity) {
        let newX
        let newY

        // please ignore the code duplication, just testing for now
        if (movingForward) {
            newX = entity.getX() - entity.speed * Math.cos(entity.direction * (Math.PI / 180))
            newY = entity.getY() - entity.speed * Math.sin(entity.direction * (Math.PI / 180))
        }
        else {
            newX = entity.getX() + entity.speed * Math.cos(entity.direction * (Math.PI / 180))
            newY = entity.getY() + entity.speed * Math.sin(entity.direction * (Math.PI / 180))
        }
        return { newX, newY }
    }

    updateCoordinatesByKeyboard(entity, keyboardInput) {
        const movingForward = keyboardInput['w']
        const movingBackwards = keyboardInput['s']

        if ((movingForward && movingBackwards) || !(movingForward || movingBackwards)) { return }
        
        const { newX, newY } = this._calculateNewCoords(movingForward, entity)
        if (this._canMove(entity, newX, newY)) { return entity.setXY(newX, newY) }
    }
```

And this is the part that renders the players:

```
drawCharacter(character, image) {
    const scale = this._getScale(character) // for a 'breathing' effect, makes character grow and shrink

    this.context.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, this.windowDimensions.width / 2, this.windowDimensions.height / 2)
    this.context.rotate(character.direction * Math.PI / 180)
    this.context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2)
}
```

Results when printing `player.direction`:

Output: `90` (as expected)

[image: Output: 90°]

Output: `180` (expect it to be 0)

[image: Output: 180°]

Output: `270` (as expected)

[image: Output: 270°]

Output: `0` (expect it to be 180)

[image: Output: 0°]

Output: `135` (expect it to be 45)

[image: Output: 135°]

Output: `315` (expect it to be 225)

[image: Output: 315°]

Again, just to reiterate - the players *move* as expected (i.e. pressing WASD makes the player turn and move correctly) - but the output `direction`s are unexpected, and I'd like to fix that because in the future I'd like to set NPCs at certain angles (i.e. facing 45°) and expect them to face that direction without having to calculate the 'mirror' direction.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does the setDirection function do? It would be useful if you could create a working snippet.

Comment: @AHaworth `setDirection` just sets the player's direction: `setDirection(direction) { this.direction = direction }`. I'll try to create a standalone snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say the values you get don't make sense - it's quite the reverse - as it's what I would expect. So it's more of a 'cosmetical' problem as it would be the same for your other game objects.

Nevertheless you can easily recalculate the output to your desired value by:

```
output = Math.abs((input + 90) % 360 - 270)
```

This will make:

90 -> 90

180 -> 0

270 -> 270

0 -> 180

135 -> 45

315 -> 225

Comment: could you please explain why the current output makes sense to you? thanks for the cosmetic fix, but I'd like to understand why I'm not seeing the numbers that intuitively make sense to me

Comment: Well I'm not sure where to start as I don't understand what you don't understand. If we go clockwise your angles go from 90->180->270->360 (though the 360 is actually 0 as it wraps around). What makes you think it's more logical if it would be 90 -> 0 -> 270 -> 180

Comment: i'm looking at a unit circle and thinking "180 points left, 0 points right" - but now that you say it like that, you're right it's about _turning_ left. Oh man. that's hilarious. Thanks @obscure!

Comment: Hehe, I know what you mean @Jona - glad I could help! =)